# How create a custom response when spring-security receives null credentials (username and password)?

Tags: spring, security, spring-security, basic-authentication, postman

I am using postman to send a username and password **without value** to my server; it's like `username=null` and `password=null`.

[image]

To control the security of my server, I use spring security 3.2. When it receives these credentials spring-security responds with this error.

```
Estado HTTP 500 - Fields must not be empty

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot pass null or empty values to constructor
    org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.<init>(User.java:99)
    org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.<init>(User.java:69)
    com.equifax.product.fraud.applicationprocessing.web.rest.interceptors.security.SecurityAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(SecurityAuthenticationProvider.java:59)
    org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:132)
    org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
    org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:177)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:168)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
```

I want output JSON with custom message with the error, how can I do that?

This is my security.xml:

```
    <security:http create-session="never" use-expressions="true"
    auto-config="false">

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/application/**"
        access="isFullyAuthenticated()" />
    <security:anonymous />
    <security:http-basic entry-point-ref="securityAccessDeniedEntryPoint" />
    <security:access-denied-handler ref="securityAccessDeniedHandler" />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"
    erase-credentials="false">
    <security:authentication-provider
        ref="genericSecurityAuthenticationProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>
```

I'am using Spring 3.2

Comment: One general question, do you use Jersey library in this project?

Comment: Second question, what Spring version do you use?

Comment: @ThomasWeglinski I'm using spring 3.2 and I dont use Jersey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the standard exception of spring security, it will handle by itself if you already have an exception handler to transform the messages into Json response.

```
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw new AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException("Fields must not be empty", exception);
        }
```

Comment: In order to this works, It's necesary create a ``entry-point-handler`` and ``access-denied-handler`` with your specific message

Answer (score 4):

You are passing the basic authentication String ":" (after base64 decoding), so as you say this results in an empty password an username. The `BasicAuthenticationFilter` passes these to the authentication provider, which is *your custom code* (`SecurityAuthenticationProvider`) so it's impossible to say exactly what it does. Somewhere in there are you are creating a `User` instance with those values, which throws the exception you are seeing. Instead you should check for empty values in your `AuthenticationProvider` and throw an `Authenticationexception`.

You will also need to override the `onUnsuccessfulAuthentication` function in the `BasicAuthenticationFilter` to write the error response you want. You'll have to configure it as a [custom filter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-custom-filters), rather than using the `<security:http-basic />` element.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is define a AuthenticationFailureHandler bean, after you implement this bean, you can do what you want inside the method onAuthenticationFailure().

XML Config:

```
<beans:bean id="myFailureHandler" class="my.custom.impl.MyCustomAuthenticationFailureHandler"/>
<security:http ....>
<security:form-login authentication-failure-handler-ref="myFailureHandler" />
</security:http>
```

http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationFailureHandler.html

Obs.: If what you want to do don't work with this solution you can implement a [AuthenticationProvider](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationProvider.html)

Comment: apper ``Estado HTTP 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is com.example.product.fraud.basic.configuration.framework.exceptions.ConfigurationNotFoundException: User Configuration Not Found.``

Comment: Another that you can do is create a exception handler

Comment: The configuration here is wrong - the failure handler needs to be set on a specific filter. However, basic authentication doesn't support an authentication failure handler so it isn't an option in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I never do it before using spring security, but I think this article describe everything that you need: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/customize-http-403-access-denied-page-in-spring-security/

Comment: No, that doesn't help here. Access denied handlers only apply for authenticated users.